# How to set radio button list text and value dynamically in data list?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can i set each list item value dynamically in radio button list?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In above radio button list the list items i want to set from database.

your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with javascript? Seems to be server–side ASP.

Comment: It definitely has to do with ASP.net, see my answer below to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must find ListItem by text and change it. Let's think, you have control :

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="yourrdblist" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="tarpiukai">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In this case you can easy change value of ListItem with text "1" to text "bambargija" :

`yourrdblist.Items.FindByText("1").Text = "bambargija";`

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Have a look at the basiscs of the RadioButtonList-Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx

If you wanna have access to the inner controls, the ListItems then acces them by using the controls property [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx).

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="inputs" runat="server" Width="50px">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

..and...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        inputs.Items.Add("input1");
        inputs.Items.Add("input2");
        inputs.Items.Add("input3");
        inputs.Items.Add("input4");
      }
    }
```